# SFSafariViewController: Audio stops on background

Tags: ios, sfsafariviewcontroller

I play audio from a webpage using `SFSafariViewController` and when the app goes to background, the audio stops.

It happens when user blocks the screen as well.

Any ideas how to keep audio playing?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Please answer if you have found any solution

Comment: Bug filed with WebKit. See https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=226163